# Numerical Reference list, with author-data in text references

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am fairly new to LaTeX and I am trying to organize my references with numerals in the bibliography, while trying to get author-date references in-text. How might someone go about doing so?

Comment: That seems strange to me: how can your readers find a reference if it is author-year in the text and numerical in the bibliography? However, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can use `biblatex` and `biber`.

Comment: This is unusual because a reader won't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use package `\usepackage{biblatex}` [(biblatex manual)](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and `biber` [(A backend bibliography processor for biblatex)](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) for compilation.

I used example bib entrys. [Example list.](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib) So everyone can test it.

**Edit:**
If you want round braces around you can use `\citep`, when adding the option `natbib=true`.

`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}`.

**Result:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Here in-text \textbf{citestyle} \textit{authoryear} with cite \cite{bertram,matuz:doody,kastenholz} and with citep \citep{gillies}
And in the \textbf{bibstyle} is \textit{numeric}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

... you can also add for example: `maxcitenames=2,ibidtracker=false,isbn=false,dashed=false,maxbibnames=50,firstinits=true,uniquelist=false`,... to customize the bib style. See: [enter link description here](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: Does it work for you?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer